# Problema al eliminar o modificar un nodo en XML

Tags: c#, xml, uwp

Tengo un proyecto en el cual manejo un archivo XML con C# UWP.

El problema es que cuando elimino o modifico un nodo del documento XML el espacio de ese nodo no se elimina y queda debajo de la raíz haciendo así que me de error.

Pongo un ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Usuario>
   <Nombre>
      <Valor>Antonio</Valor>
   </Nombre>
   <Contrasena>
      <Valor>Antonio1989</Valor>
   </Contrasena>
   <Apellido>
      <Valor>Pérez</Valor>
   </Apellido>
</Usuario>
```

Así es como se vería sin ningún cambio, pero cuando elimino por ejemplo el nodo "Contraseña" queda algo así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Usuario>
   <Nombre>
      <Valor>Antonio</Valor>
   </Nombre>
   <Apellido>
      <Valor>Pérez</Valor>
   </Apellido>
</Usuario>o>
      <Valor>Pérez</Valor>
   </Apellido>
</Usuario>
```

El fragmento de código que utilizo en C# es el siguiente (el "path" es un `IsolatedStorageFileStream`):

```
public void EliminarNodo(string nodo)
{
   XmlDocument Documento = new XmlDocument();
   Documento.Load(path);

   XmlElement Root = Documento.DocumentElement;
   XmlNode NodoEliminar = Root.GetElementsByTagName(nodo)[0];
   Root.RemoveChild(NodoEliminar);

   Documento.Save(AlmacenDatos.Stream(Ruta));
}
```

Comment: Imagino que el problema es que el archivo xml ya existe. Has probado a eliminarlo antes de hacer el save? Otra opción tal vez sea al crear el `IsolatedStorageFileStream` ponerle `FileMode.Truncate`

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos en contenido de `AlmacenDatos.Stream(Ruta)`?

Comment: Tu pregunta me causa mucha curiosidad. Has tenido algun resultado?

Comment: De momento ninguna respuesta me ha servido. El Stream básicamente es abrir un IsolatedStorageFile y un IsolatedStorageFileStream con la ruta, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, y el ISF abierto anteriormente. Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes eliminar el nodo a través de un `XElement`:

```
XElement XML = XElement.Load(path);
EliminaNodos(XML.Element("Usuario").Element("Contraseña"));
```

Método que elimina el nodo:

```
public void EliminaNodo(XElement nodoAEliminar)
{
    nodoAEliminar.RemoveNodes();
}
```

De igual forma, para eliminar el nodo, puedes hacer uso de los métodos `Remove();` y/o `RemoveAll();`